# source toaster start failed with error start django although it is exists

Tags: python, linux, django, yocto

I am trying to start the Yocto toaster.

I installed python 2.7 and django.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ImportError: No module named 'django' This program needs
>   Django>1.8,<1.9 Please install with pip install -r
>   /home/elia/YoctoProject/poky/bitbake/toaster-requirements.txt

I also tried using virtual environments.

The sys path is:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/home/elia/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

`django-admin --version` returns 1.8.18

And from the python itself I am getting the django version ok

```
print(django.get_version())
1.8.18
```

without the error that source toaster start 
is telling.

What should I do to start toaster?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the required packages for toaster, if you are using yocto version below 2.1(krogoth) then use below command in your command line.

```
pip install -r /home/elia/YoctoProject/poky/bitbake/toaster-requirements.txt
```

If you are using yocto version above 2.2(morty) use below command

```
pip3 install -r /home/elia/YoctoProject/poky/bitbake/toaster-requirements.txt
```

Note: Below versions of `yocto-2.1(krogoth)` depends on python and pip

From `yocto-2.2(morty`) it will depends on python3 and pip3

Check which version of yocto you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command in your source `poky$`

```
pip install -r /home/elia/YoctoProject/poky/bitbake/toaster-requirements.txt
```